# Flask-Admin not working on Production server (CSS and JS not loading)

Tags: python, flask, production-environment, flask-admin, http-status-code-500

I'm facing a problem with Flask Admin. **Here is the problem:**

When running Flask on localhost, everything works fine but once in production, all the static file from Flask-admin are not loading properly. [Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHU2d.png)

In the end, I get a page that loads indefinitely.

I really need some help !

Comment: Did you figure it out?